# Do I need to add containers for partial views? (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

The `_Layout.cshtml` already has a container `div` for the entire body. For the partial views, should I add another container `div` on each one of them or the main one is enough? I don't mind adding extra code, but I would like to know what the best practice is on this subject.

```
  <div class="container body-content" >
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year/p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to, but I think it's good to have that distinction. It doesn't complicate your program but it does provide a more structured generated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to have specific containers for your partial views. But if you are using AJAX and want to refresh only some very specific portion of your markup (and not the entire div that the Layout provides you), then wrapping it in a container would help.

So I would say that you should add a container around your partial view if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason I add containers around my partial views is solely for populating it with ajax JSON results and or for organizational purposes. Think of a partial view as a web controller in Web Forms. The need for the use of a container is based solely on what you are using it for. So, the answer is no, you do not need to put your partial views in a container. For a best practice approach, you should. Though, dependigon how complicated your view is, the parent view is technically your partials container.

For emxample. Say you have tab contents, and each content is a partial view. If you have it in a container, yoou can now make a ajax request to a controller action that returns JSOn, to populate that partial view.

Example: This is a content area where I place a partial view.

```
<div id="selectLanguageWrapper">
<!-- the model is supplied via modal load via jquery-->
<div id="selectLanguageModal" class="modal  fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="500">
</div>
```

The view is here:

```
 @model SiteModel

<!-- user input modal  -->    
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Create Site</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">   
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSite", "Settings", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal col-md-10", role = "form", id = "createSiteForm" }))
            {               
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(sm => sm.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Site Name"})
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="text tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(sm => sm.Name)
                 </div>
                 <div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EnvironmentID)                   
                 </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="createSiteButton">@Resources.Create</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelButton">@Resources.Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

And the controller to return the view

```
public ActionResult LoadCreateSite(int id)
        {
            SiteModel model = new SiteModel()
            {
                EnvironmentID = id,

                PrimaryLanguageID = Settings.DefaultLanguageID,

                IsDefault = false,

                IsEnabled = false,

                ExternalURL = "localhost:55975",

                InternalURL = "Default",

            DefaultSiteAvatarFileName = "Default"
            };

            var partial = RenderRazorViewToString("Properties/_createSite", model);

            return Json(new { Response = AjaxResponse.Success, Message = partial }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

And the javascript that loads that content:

```
$("#createSiteModal").delegate("#createSiteButton", "click", function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        id = $("#EnvironmentID").val();
        name = $("#Name").val();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Settings/CreateSite',
        data: { id: id, name: name },
        success: function (ret) {
            if (ret.Response == RESPONSE.SUCCESS) {
                $.when($("#properties").html(ret.Message)).then(function () {
                    $('.accordion > dd').hide();
                    $("#createSiteModal").modal("hide");                        
                });                 
            }
            if (ret.Response == RESPONSE.ERROR) {
                console.error("Error: There was an unknown error while creating new site!");
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ajaxErrorHandler(jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

That is why I always use a container around my partial views, and name the container somthing like "wrapper-[partialviewname]. Hopefully this helps.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You would generally want to wrap your partial-views in a container and attach an ID to that specific container so that you can select it in the future in order to populate it or refresh it's contents via AJAX.

Just adding a container would probably not be sufficient as the bootstrap containers are classes. What you want to do is specify a div that has a class called container and an Id for example: login-partial

This lets you select the parent for your partial:-)